# How to prepare a C++ string for sql query

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I have to prepare strings to be suitable for queries because these strings will be used in the queries as field values. if they contain a ' etc the sql query fails to execute.

I therefore want to replace ' with '' I have seen the code to find and replace a substring with a substring. but I guess the problem is a little tricky because replacing string also contains two single quotes '' replacing one quote '  so when I have to find the next occurance it would encounter a ' which was intentionally replaced.

I am using Sql lite C api and the example query might look like this

```
 select * from persons where name  = 'John' D'oe'
```

Since John Doe contain a ' the query will fail , so I want all occurances of ' in the name to replaced with ''

Any ideas how you guys prepares your field values in query to be used in sql ??? may be it's a basic thing but I am not too smart in C/C++.

your help would be very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use queries with arguments instead of replacing stuff, which could lead to several problems (like SQL injection vulnerabilities).

MySQL example:

```
sql::Connection *con = ...;
string query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = ?";
sql::PreparedStatement *prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement(query);
prep_stmt->setInt(1, 1); // Replace first argument with 1
prep_stmt->execute();
```

This will execute `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1`.

**EDIT**: more info for SQLite prepared statements [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) and [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer is sql::Connection and sql::PreparedStatement part of sqlite C api ? I can not find it

Comment: It clearly states: **MySQL example**. You forgot the SQLite tag in your question and added it after my answer. I added links to you on how to it with SQLite C API.

Comment: Thanks, I find you pointed to the right direction and I accept it as part of this question but unfortunately using the C api'I am having issues that's why I have a particular question on C sqlite api.

Comment: Again, I have linked you on how to do it with SQLite C API in the answer. Please take your time to read the whole answer and comments.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the SQL Library you are using.  Some of them will have the concept of a PreparedStatement, which you will use question marks in place of the variables, then when you set those variables on the statement, it will internally ensure that you cannot inject sql commands.

Comment: I see, I am using sqlite C++ apis, does it have something that I can use ?

Comment: you should be able to call query.prepare(), that's where you set the SQL query and set it up with variables.  You don't want to roll your own code for anti-sql-injection, just use the prepared statement concept of the api