# sqlite query not prepared row insterted but empty values

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am writing a function to prepare a sql query and execute it against a sqlite db. I am using a query to insert values in to a table, the query looks like this

```
   "insert into files values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0)";
```

A row is inserted but all values for text fields are empty except the last field which is 0. The first 5 fields are of type TEXT

```
    // If I hard code a value for value.data() then the row is inserted correctly with my hardcoded data, the exact line is below
    status = sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt, index, /* if I hardcode it works*/ value.data(), -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

The full function is shown below.The list is created on stack by the calller, I am not sure why it is not replacing question marks with my string args, hardcoded ones work though.. no error codes are returned

```
    //db is already open before I call this
void MediaCache::prepareAndExecuteQuery(string query, list<string> args)
{

    sqlite3_stmt *ppStmt = 0;
    const char **pzTail = 0;
    int status = 0;

    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.data(), query.length(), &ppStmt, pzTail) != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        string error = sqlite3_errmsg(db);
        //throw an exception
    } 

    if(ppStmt)
    {

        list<string>::iterator current = args.begin();
        int index = 1;

        for(current = args.begin() ; current != args.end(); current++)
        {
            string value = *current;            
            status = sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt, index, value.data(), -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

            if(status != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //log error;
            }

            index++;
        }   

        status = sqlite3_step(ppStmt);
        status = sqlite3_finalize(ppStmt);
        //sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        //ppStmt is null
        //throw an exception
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the datatype of column 0-4. ?

Comment: type is TEXT for first 5 fields

Comment: I already answered this in your previous question. See how to bind arguments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483120/how-to-prepare-a-c-string-for-sql-query/14483389#14483389).

Comment: You could use a `std::stringstream` for that.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes I know there was an answer but it was a C# answer, here it is my specifc question about C api which is not working and I am trying to find out why it's not working

Comment: That's a C++ answer, not C#. And you're using C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
string value = *current;            
status = sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt, index, value.data(), -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

In this case `value` goes out of scope before the execution of the statement takes place.  So the pointers given to `sqlite3_bind_text` are no longer valid.  To "fix" that, you could use SQLITE_TRANSIENT, which would force the library to make its own copy of the data before returning.

Also, if you are not using C++11, I don't believe `string::data()` is guaranteed to be NULL terminated in which case the -1 parameter could be incorrect.  It should maybe be `value.length()` instead.

Comment: Mark, would you use a reference or const reference instead of a copy in this case? And I concur I think at least something like `c_str()` would be more appropriate for the string constant.

Comment: @WhozCraig:  I think that using (*current).data() would be okay.  As long as the strings are not changed before the execution occurs, I believe those pointers would be valid.

Comment: Thanks Mark,using SQLITE_TRANSIENT or current->data() with SQLITE_STATIC work your observation was correct value goes out of scope before execution. does c_str() guarantree a null terminates c string ? I am developing on windows visual studio but eventually it will also compile on xode on mac

Comment: @Ahmed: Yes, c_str is supposed to guarantee a null terminator.